# dynamically updating html page in rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an html text-area which uses ajax-autocomplete where it populates the dropdown as i start typing. When I select an entry from the dropdown it will set some field to the id of that object.

Once I get the id of the object is there a way I could do something like this?

```
<% @myObjects.find(1) do |myObj| %>
  <h1><%= myObj.attr1 %><h1>
  <h2><%= myObj.attr1 %><h2>
<% end %>
```

Right now, when I get the id of the object I am using jquery's attr() function to set the values which exposes my javascript logic which I don't really like. Is there a way I can activate the field? Or, hide the fields and where the id is populated show the field and let ruby do its magic with myObjects.find?

UPDATE:

Right now the way I am populating the fields in the view like this:

```
$(function() {      
  // Executes a callback detecting changes with a frequency of 1 second
  $("#id_element_placeholder").observe_field(1, function(){                                     
    //alert('Change observed! new value: ' + this.value );
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/myobj/get/" + this.value,
      success: function(data){
        $('#last_name').attr('value', data.myobj.last_name);
        $('#first_name').attr('value', data.myobj.first_name);                  
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Is there a way around exposing the above javascript code?

Comment: Please provide some mark-up and/or try to explain what you're trying to achieve from e.g. the user's perspective. I can't really figure out what your goal is. Also — everything you do with Javascript is accessible to the user. No way of preventing that. If that's what you meant by "which exposes my javascript logic which I don't really like".

Comment: Check out the updated post, I've posted the code that I use now to populated fields in html.

Comment: I also don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to run a new find on @myObjects after the Ajax call returns? Please paste some HTML of the expected result.

Comment: @user140736 - Why are you worried about hiding that JavaScript code?  I can show you dozens and dozens of versions of other people making AJAX calls and then updating the user interface.  You don't seem to be doing anything Earth-shattering here.  With that said, if you're still concerned, just use a JavaScript code obfuscator like Consyntools Obfuscator.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your javascript and you seem to be confused between client side and server side technologies. Ruby cannot directly update your page once it has been sent to your user. It is on your web server and your page has been sent to the clients browser. It can however send javascript in response to a further request made by your application from the clients browser to do exactly that, just as you are doing.

You could send a new html snippet to your browser and replace the entire node but really there is no point. What you are doing is the same as everybody else who uses javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, you can't :)
What you are doing is ok, using AJAX for such things is the way to have such a things done.
If you are concerned about exposures don't look at javascript, look at what the server side code allow a user to do with get/post methods ;)

Comment: I down voted you for an incomplete and extremely vague answer which duplicated what I had said but with brevity and ambiguity. 'Look at what the server side code allow you to do with post get/methods'. Explain a get/post method. His application is already sending requests via ajax, whether get or post, with methods responding according to his application's defined routes.